# Angular 8 - Load an external component angular in Angular module

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular project that at some point also carries an external component in Angular.

I can easily load it into the project's index.html, however, when trying to load it into a module, it doesn't recognize the tag.

ex:

Index.html:

```
<script src = "https: //componenturl.com \"> </script>
<extrnal-component> </extrnal-component>
```

However, doing the same thing in the component presents me with the following error:

> 'extrnal-component' is not a known element.

how do I load this component correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a spelling error. "external-component" not "extrnal-component"

Comment: No, extrnal-component is an alias for my variable. In the code the variable has another name but I didn't want to make it explicit here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by dynamically appending the tag  in the my component.

**comp.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Renderer2, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

...
constructor(
   private elementRef: ElementRef, 
   private renderer: Renderer2,
   @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document
){}

...

const child = document.createElement('extrnal-component');
this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, child);
```

I loaded the script tag at the end of component.html and this way it worked correctly

Thank you all

Comment: I tried this and I got "A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation" on the @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document line.

Answer (score 2):

The following checks could be done:

I can see a spelling mistake. It says `extrnal-component` and not `external-component`.

Are you calling it from the same module? If so, have you declared the component in the module's declarations?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ExternalComponent],
    imports: [...],
})
```

Is ExternalComponent a part of a different module? If so, have you declared it in its module's declarations as well as in its exports?

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ExternalComponent],
    imports: [...],
    exports: [ExternalComponent],
})
```

Comment: No, extrnal-component is an alias for my variable. In the code the variable has another name but I didn't want to make it explicit here

Comment: The external component is a part of the angular app on a URL, not in the same server

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the component with the application module?

Assuming the component class is declared in the typescript ifle "../components/external/external.component"

```
import { ExtrnalComponent } from "../components/external/external.component"

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        ExtrnalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       ....
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: The external component is a part of the angular app on a URL, not in the same server